# Laravel: Update from 5.2.12 to 5.2.31

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have a Laravel **5.2.12** project (website), it's a big project and it's almost finished... Is there any simple way to update the Laravel from  **5.2.12** to **5.2.31** without affecting the project (without affecting what was already done)? How can I do this?

So, the question is how to update the version of Laravel on existing project from **5.2.12** to **5.2.31**?

EDIT: Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "cartalyst/sentinel": "2.0.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.2",
        "slynova/laravel-commentable": "^2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

What should be changed to update just Laravel to **5.2.31** (to the latest 5.2 version)?

Comment: Minor versions are always backward compatible so no issue with updating. It's even required in a security point of view to update on a regular base.

Comment: `composer update laravel/framework`

Comment: @SimonSvensson Running this command updated my Laravel to **5.2.20** instead of **5.2.31**?

Comment: That means that your current packages is compatible with 5.2.20, but not 5.2.21 (or higher). A look at packagist shows that 5.2.21 started required psy/psysh 0.7.* (from previous 0.6.*). Try `composer update laravel/framework --with-dependencies` or `composer update laravel/framework psy/psysh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `composer.json` to use `laravel\laravel` on the version you would like. Then run `composer update` in you command line.

Your project should not have any issues updating from `5.2.12` to `5.2.31` since they are mostly bugfixes. But do note that other dependencies might update to a new version. So you might want to set them to a fixed version in your `composer.json` file if the cause hickups.

Comment: I think you mean `composer update` the `composer.lock` files contains the exact versions. Normally there is no need to adjust the composer file

Comment: Also it's better to not lock the versions in your composer.json file but to use a pattern like `1.0.*`. This way you can't miss minor updates such as security fixes and other bug fixes

Comment: It's a note, not a requirement. If the OP is doubtfull about newer versions of packages and their compatibility with his code. But yeah most definitely they wont cause any problems.

Comment: @JhonnyWalker I have edited my question, I have added the content of my `composer.json`. There is `laravel/framework": "5.2.*` so I guess that I just need to run the `composer update` command and it will update it to the latest **5.2** version (**5.2.31**), right? What about config files (or my controllers, blade views, models...), those will be preserved? Also, if you look at my `composer.json` - you can see the other packages that were installed... So, by running `composer update` do I risk to update those packages to versions that will not be compatible with Laravel **5.2**?

Comment: @PerkaMika Yes it will update you framework to the last stabel `5.2` version and thrid party packages will compatible with the `5.2` release. There's some checks that happen.